# Events Calendar - error on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, calendar

I’m creating an events calendar..

I’m facing a problem. My events calendar app works fine in Samsung Galaxy Y and HTC devices but when I run the apk in Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 it throws the error shown in the logcat below. I'm unable able to find the solution.

**Logcat**

```
09-03 12:24:08.703: E/AndroidRuntime(8676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 12:24:08.703: E/AndroidRuntime(8676): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 12:24:08.703: E/AndroidRuntime(8676):     at com.examples.android.calendar.Utility.readCalendarEvent(Utility.java:36)
09-03 12:24:08.703: E/AndroidRuntime(8676):     at com.examples.android.calendar.CalendarView$1.run(CalendarView.java:184)
```

**CalendarView.java**

```
public class CalendarView extends Activity {

    public GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.

    public CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
    public Handler handler;// for grabbing some event values for showing the dot
                            // marker.
    public ArrayList<String> items; // container to store calendar items which
                                    // needs showing the event marker
    ArrayList<String> event;
    LinearLayout rLayout;
    ArrayList<String> date;
    ArrayList<String> desc;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calendar);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

        rLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.text);
        month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();

        items = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(this, month);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater);

        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));

        RelativeLayout previous = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.previous);

        previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout next = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();

            }
        });

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                // removing the previous view if added
                if (((LinearLayout) rLayout).getChildCount() > 0) {
                    ((LinearLayout) rLayout).removeAllViews();
                }
                desc = new ArrayList<String>();
                date = new ArrayList<String>();
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);
                String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.dayString
                        .get(position);
                String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
                String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*",
                        "");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
                int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
                // navigate to next or previous month on clicking offdays.
                if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                    setPreviousMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                    setNextMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v);

                for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                    if (Utility.startDates.get(i).equals(selectedGridDate)) {
                        desc.add(Utility.nameOfEvent.get(i));
                    }
                }

                if (desc.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < desc.size(); i++) {
                        TextView rowTextView = new TextView(CalendarView.this);

                        // set some properties of rowTextView or something
                        rowTextView.setText("Event:" + desc.get(i));
                        rowTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                        // add the textview to the linearlayout
                        rLayout.addView(rowTextView);

                    }

                }

                desc = null;

            }

        });
    }

    protected void setNextMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                    month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }

    }

    protected void setPreviousMonth() {
        if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            month.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }

    }

    protected void showToast(String string) {
        Toast.makeText(this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void refreshCalendar() {
        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

        adapter.refreshDays();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.post(calendarUpdater); // generate some calendar items

        title.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", month));
    }

    public Runnable calendarUpdater = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.clear();

            // Print dates of the current week
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            String itemvalue;
            event = Utility.readCalendarEvent(CalendarView.this); ///Line 184
            Log.d("=====Event====", event.toString());
            Log.d("=====Date ARRAY====", Utility.startDates.toString());

            for (int i = 0; i < Utility.startDates.size(); i++) {
                itemvalue = df.format(itemmonth.getTime());
                itemmonth.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
                items.add(Utility.startDates.get(i).toString());
            }
            adapter.setItems(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

**Utility.java**

```
public class Utility {
public static ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> endDates = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                    new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                            "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                    null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // fetching calendars name
    String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

    // fetching calendars id
    nameOfEvent.clear();
    startDates.clear();
    endDates.clear();
    descriptions.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

        nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
        startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3).trim())));
        endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4).trim())));
        descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
        CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
        cursor.moveToNext();

    }
    return nameOfEvent;
}

public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}}
```

Comment: Formatting and improvents to question.